# MediaPlayer duration return 0 when stream mp3

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I make a application use MediaPlayer to stream mp3 from google driver: (Ex:https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B50eyu1h_Rc1bENYOU1iSjFWaVk)

on update time funtion:

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        // Displaying time completed playing
        songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration - currentDuration));
        // Updating progress bar
        int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
        songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
        // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

I see that long `totalDuration = mp.getDuration()` always return 0 in spite of mediaplayer played.

How can I get the length of media ?

Comment: getCurrentPosition() returning correct values?